# write phpunit test function for a service class

Tags: phpunit

Hi guys i am trying to create a phpunit test for below function.

```
/**
 * Get file size
 *
 * @param string $filePath
 * @return int
 */
public function getFileSize(string $filePath): int
{
    if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return filesize($filePath);
}
```

So far i have tried like this

```
/**
 * Test get file size with invalid data
 */
public function testGetFileSizeWithValidData()
{
    $filePath = 'rgreherher';
    $service = new Tickets_Service_ContactMomentVehicle();
    $result = $service->getFileSize($filePath);

    $this->assertSame($result, $filePath);
}
```

So when i run in my terminal i am getting error as

```
<string:rgreherher> does not match expected type "integer".
```

Can anyone help me what mistake i have done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what is going on, you are comparing an integer (`$result`) to a string (`$filePath`).

If I understand your test case correctly, you should replace `$filePath` with `$filePath`'s size instead.

```
public function testGetFileSizeWithValidData()
{
    $filePath = 'rgreherher';
    $filePathSize = 55; // actual file size of $filePath

    $service = new Tickets_Service_ContactMomentVehicle();
    $result = $service->getFileSize($filePath);

    $this->assertSame($result, $filePathSize);
}
```

Comment: i am getting same error again and you haven't pass $filepathsize anywhere?

Comment: @suresh I've fixed the `assertSame` to pass `$filePathSize`. You are now comparing two integers, does this help you understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your test you assume that the file exists, but if not you must remember that php function [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#refsect1-function.filesize-returnvalues) (which is in your function getFileSize) returns false and generates an E_WARNING if there is no file.